# wpf combobox default behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a combobox in a wpf c# application.

What i am trying to do is the following.

I have a unselected combobox, as you look at it i can see an arrow to the right hand side and a space for text on the left. For the purpose of this question i'll refer to this text as 'Cell Text'.

When you select the button it appears with a list. I want this list to contain a number of robots my GUI/PC can connect to. When i select a robot, a message is sent to this robot trying to connect with it.

The 'Cell Text' i want to display the name of the currently connected Robot. There will be situations when a connection to a selected robot would'nt be possible, also a successful connection could take 5 seconds.

What i need to do is stop the selection automatically appearing in the 'Cell Text', is this possible?

Thanks

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyRobotOptions}" Grid.Column="1" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRobot}" Margin="5"/>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically appearing"?  Do you mean that you want to have the concept of a null or empty selection?  eg. do you want it to be empty intially without a robot selected?

Comment: when i select a robot, i don't want the selection to appear immediately, i only want it to update when a variable "ConnectedRobot" updates. Not when i make a selection.

Comment: What about adding a `Timer` or something similar inside the [SelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged.aspx) Event?

Comment: but there is no guarantee the "ConnectedRobot" variable will change, hence ruling out a timer. Is there no way i can bind the 'Cell Text' to a separate variable and have the SelectedItem bound to a separate? and stop the SelectedItem updating the 'Cell Text'

Answer (score 0):

For an inexperienced user (no offence), one of the easiest ways you can do this is to overlay a `TextBlock` over the 'Cell Text', as you call it:

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyRobotOptions}" Grid.Column="1" SelectedItem="{
        Binding SelectedRobot}" Margin="5" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding YourSelectedRobotName}" Background="White" 
        Margin="0,0,24,0" />
</Grid>
```

I haven't been able to test this, so you might need to adjust the `Margin` property values to make it fit better, but it should hide the original text value.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution I think is to use a separate indicator for connection state. For example a colored border around the Combobox that turns green when connected, red when disconnected. That way you don't have to break the paradigm of a ComboBox that everyone assumes: when you select something it immediately appears selected in the ComboBox.